# Using dynamic topology makes weird artifacts

Tags: mesh, sculpting

When sculpting with dynamic topology, there's this weird sort of artifacting issue that occurs when using the subtract option with the crease brush, where it doesn't make a crease in the way I expect it to, but instead sort of flattens out the area, while only slightly creating the the crease I want (I usually use crease, but it seems like any subtraction version of a brush causes weird artifacting).
[image]
This sort of thing doesn't seem to happen if I only subdivide it and sculpt without dynamic topology on. It may also be notable that the same thing happens in Blender 2.8, for what it's worth.

Comment: what Detail Size rate have you chosen?

Comment: Current it's at the default 12.00.

Comment: Perhaps decrease the size, perhaps it's in Collapse Edges mode instead of Subdivide Edges? Hard to tell, could you please share your file?

Comment: Lowering the detail size does seem to have help (and in 2.8 too), thank you! Though here's the original file if you think it may still be good to take a look at it. https://app.box.com/s/aedg5kram9hzgox0j8xxljts4kswbhf9

Comment: Yes your Detail Size must have been too high, and as your Refine Method was either Collapse Edges or Subdivide Collapse it has created large triangles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Properties* panel > *Tool* > *Dyntopo*, Your *Detail Size* is too high, and as your *Refine Method* was either on *Collapse Edges* or on *Subdivide Collapse* it was creating large triangles and bad artifacts. So, decrease the *Detail Size* from 12 to 2 for example.