# Blender model has triangular artifacts when brought into other software

Tags: modeling

I have modelled a character in blender and have exported it into substance painter to texture it. However,  I get these weird triangular artifacts.

What are they and how can I fix them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119387/using-dynamic-topology-makes-weird-artifacts/119401#119401 - still working on the problem rn

Comment: I highly recommend you retopo the model or use a remesher to give it cleaner topology, this will make texturing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts like this occur as a result of really poor UV mapping.

I was using the automatic UV unwrap function. Upon actually putting in the seams manually, all of the artifacts disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but it looks like you have a Vertex Color in your mesh. When using dyntopo in faces with Vertex Color, the color in these faces will be erased resulting in a sharp transition between the sculpted and unaltered faces.

Before sculpt, brush with Dyntopo:

[image: Vertex Color before retopo brush]

After sculpt, brush with Dyntopo:

[image: Vertex Color after retopo brush]

Perhaps the other software you're using is showing you a Vertex Color that is in your mesh.

Comment: Interesting pickup. I unfortunately can't test the issue out but i'll give you an upvote because its a good solution